# No puedo unir a dos usuarios a una misma room con socket.io

Tags: nodejs, socket, express, join

Estoy haciendo una app con express, mongoose, y socket.io. Mi intención es hacer que cuando un usuario ingrese, se una a una *room* cuyo nombre es el nombre de la ciudad con la que se registró. La idea es que cuando un usuario A y B pertenezcan a una misma ciudad, estén unidos a la misma *room*. Pero no logro que me funcione. Cuando un usuario A, emite información a la *room*, esta información no llega al usuario B, ni a los demás conectados a esta.

este es mi archivo del lado del servidor:

***app.js***

```
var express = require('express');
// .. others modules here .. 

var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

// my custom routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');

// socket.io config
io.on('connection',function(socket){

    console.log("new user connected id socket: "+socket.id);

    // evento disparado cuando un usuario inicia sesion
    socket.on("join", function(data){
        socket.join(data);
        console.log("connected to room: "+data);
        console.log(io.nsps["/"].adapter);
    });

    //evento que recibe el nombre de la ciudad a la que emitirán datos
    socket.on("notificar",function(ciudad){
        console.log("sending data to: "+ciudad);
        io.to(ciudad).emit("recibir",{message: "new "+ciudad});
    });

});

server.listen(3000, function () {
  //console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Todas las páginas del lado del cliente incluyen el script ***socket-client.js*** para la conexión con el servidor.

***socket-client.js***

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('connection', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// para enviar datos a la room
$("#form-report").on('submit',function(i,e){
    // city es la ciudad que será el nombre de la room
    var city = $("#report-city").html();
    socket.emit("notificar",city);
});

// para recibir datos de la room
socket.on('recibir', function(socketData){
    alert("recibiendo datos: "+socketData);
});
```

El archivo validate-user.js es un archivo que captura el usuario y contraseña del formulario de login, y valida si existe. Si es así, entonces dispara el evento join del servidor.

***validate-user.js***

```
// usuario y contraseña desdel el formulario 
input_email = $("form#form-login input#email");
input_pass = $("form#form-login input#password");

$("#btn-login").on('click',function(i,e){
    email = input_email.val();
    pass = input_pass.val();

    // petición para validar si existe
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/autenticate/'+email+'/'+pass,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.exist === false){
                $("#label-email").html(data.message);
                return true;
                input_email.val("");
                input_pass.val("");
            }else{
                // SI EXISTE disparar e vento "join" del servidor
                socket.emit("join",data.data.ciudad);
                location.href = "http://localhost:3000/"+email;
            }
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

El problema entonces es que cuando se conectan los dos usuarios de la misma ciudad, no se unen en la misma sala. Aquí dejo unos screenshoots cuando se conectó el usuario A y posteriormente el usuario B.

***screenshoots***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
usuario A conectado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
usuario B conectado

Comment: Porque haces que el usuario se una a la sala y luego cambias la url de la página con `location.href = "http://localhost:3000/"+email`. Esto no hace que tu usuario se desconecte automaticamente?

Comment: hola @MarcLemein, gracias por tu comentario. estuve haciendo pruebas, y no sabia ese detalle, que la conexion se pierde una vez es dirigido a otra pagina web. hice pruebas y confirmé que es cierto. ¿hay una forma de mantener ese socket mientras el usuario navega por otras paginas de la app que estoy haciendo? porque pensé que con incluir el archivo ***socket-client.js*** en todas mis paginas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que estás viendo una sola sala es porque el cliente se desconecta cuando cambias la url con `location.href`. Socket.io crea conexión persistente usando websockets o long pooling por lo que cuando cambias de página esta se pierde.

Puedes notar el síntoma si verificas los ids de tus usuarios conectados, en la primera foto el id es `iMrhv5ovjeojs7XEAAAA`. En la segunda hay dos ids completamente diferentes `iYSCz-5kxqX_kAbyAAA` y `zDgiEMHg-NyFqz-KAAAC` la reconexión de tu primer cliente y el nuevo que se conecta.

Posibles soluciones hay 2

La primera es incluir el fichero **socket-client.js** luego de validar todos los datos y que ya sepas en que room lo vas a poner, esto sería luego de navegar a la url `http://localhost:3000/{email}`

**socket-client.js**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
var cuidad;

socket.on('connection', function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    socket.emit("join", ciudad);
});

// No se incluye los datos para unirse a la room porque esta se debe obtener de otra forma

// para recibir datos de la room
socket.on('recibir', function(socketData){
    alert("recibiendo datos: "+socketData);
});
```

El problema de esta vía es que debes obtener de nuevo el dato de la ciudad cuando cambias de página. Puedes hacer esto solicitándoselo al servidor por ajax, pasandolo en la query o guardandolo en el localStorage.

La segunda vía es no cambiar de página o usar el hash para que la página no se actualize y pierdas la conexión

fragmento de **validate-user.js**

```
// .......
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/autenticate/'+email+'/'+pass,
    success: function(data){
        if(data.exist === false){
            $("#label-email").html(data.message);
            input_email.val("");
            input_pass.val("");
        }else{
            // SI EXISTE disparar e vento "join" del servidor
            socket.emit("join",data.data.ciudad);
            // Eliminar esta línea o usar el hash(#) como se muestra debajo
            location.href = "http://localhost:3000/#"+email;
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
// ....
```

De esta forma tu página no cambiará y la conexión no se perderá. Esta variante es muy útil si estás haciendo un SPA porque la url **sí** cambiará sin hacer una actualización completa de la página.

Comment: Justo antes de leer tu respuesta probé la primera alternativa, y justo cuando ya autentico al usuario, almaceno el dato de la ciudad en un localStorge, asi cada vez que el usuario se desconecte del socket y se vuelva a conectar

Comment: @devmingo Yo no conozco todos los detalles de tu aplicación pero si la primera vez que te conectas no envias ni recibes nada por el socket porque aún debes autenticarte puedes tomar mi sugerencia y conectarte cuando ya tienes todos los datos necesarios. Es un simple asunto de eficiencia, tu eres libre de implementarlo como quieras. ;)